# creating weekly reminders for only weekdays - swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, reminders

I currently have an array of weekdays and wish to set them as reminders weekly  - here is the code so far.

```
for i in selectedWeekDay {
                        
                        let dateInfo = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .weekday], from: timeSet as! Date)
                               dateInfo.hour
                               dateInfo.minute
                               dateInfo.weekday = i

                        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: true)
                                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                        
                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {error in
                            if error != nil
                            {
                                print("something went wrong")
                            }
                        })
                       
                    }
```

this code is run in a for loop that goes through the `selectedWeekDay`

the `selectedWeekDay` stores an array of integers that represents weekdays

I then want to set up the `dateInfo` by setting the time from the variable "timeSet" - the "timeSet" stores only the time from a UIDatePicker.

I then assign it to the `dateInfo`.

I wanted to add a weekday into the "dateInfo" but I get this error message in the `dateInfo.weekday = i` saying:

`Cannot assign to property: 'dateInfo' is a 'let' constant`

once I changed the `dateInfo` to be a var I get two other error messages in my `dateInfo.hour` and  `dateInfo.minute`  saying:

`Expression resolves to an unused property`

can anyone help me solve this issue? thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to do with dateInfo.hour (and minute)?

Comment: i want to use the dateInfo.hour and minute to trigger the notification and that specific time - and use the dateInfo.weekday to trigger that time and the specified weekday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the hour and minute in the loop and actually it is better to create `dateInfo` before the loop and then update the `weekday` inside the loop

```
var dateInfo = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .weekday], from: timeSet as! Date)
for i in selectedWeekDay {
    dateInfo.weekday = i

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: true)
    //... rest of code
}
```

Comment: okay i just implemented that into my project but when i specified the dateInfo.hour and minute outside the loop i get the same errors - do you have a why to include the  dateInfo. minute and hour?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean really, does it work if your implement it like I suggest in my answer?

Comment: sorry - you are right - thanks for the help, all of the errors are now gone

Comment: sorry i am new to this - i just did

Answer (score 0):

Set var dateInfo and remove hour && minute, u don't need to call it without set value.

```
var dateInfo = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .weekday], from: timeSet as! Date)
//dateInfo.hour
//dateInfo.minute
dateInfo.weekday = i
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention this. when I trigger the notification the dateInfo.hour and minute will have a value - the value was set in a datePicker on a different screen - I then want to trigger that notification at the specified hour and minute that the user has set from the timeSet and than trigger it from the array of weekdays - for example, I set the time 10:00 pm and stored that value in timeSet and wanted to trigger that time on mon, wen, fri - so is there a way to keep dateInfo.hour and minute?

Comment: dateInfo's hour and minute is timeSet u input,it doesn't need to reset again.